# Any Perl Module for repetitive search and extract of a file's content?

Tags: perl

I need to parse some log files where the data is repetitive in a particular pattern. I need to search for particular 'keywords' in the data and then extract data from next lines. I need to continue this for the whole file.
I know this can be done using basic perl scripting. But do we have any perl module that simplifies this kind of feature?

Comment: If it can be done with a basic script, what's the point of writing a module?

Comment: Hi Mat, i don't want to write a module, but just checking if there's any module targeted at this kind of activity which gives more options and control.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there's no such module, because the code is quite trivial, and OTOH *the details are quite problem-specific*.

I've had this similar problem many times. The input has been something like:

```
Date: 2011-11-10
<an interesting line>
<another interesting line>
Date: 2011-11-11
<more interesting lines>
```

And I've needed to extract all "interesting lines" while knowing the date for each. I think oneliners or short throwaway scripts have been very successful for the purpose. With oneliners, it's good to be familiar with useful things like `-l` and `-a`. `perl -wlane '...'` it's something I've written a thousand time.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at `cgrep`, which is an example of exactly this type of processing. It can be used in a pipeline, i.e.

```
cat mylog | cgrep -w0:1 'regexp' | grep -v 'regexp' | sed 's/.../.../'
```

In other words grep for regexp, outputting 0 lines before the match and one after, then remove the original matches, and format the result. You may not want to use `sed` for the last step, it's just an example.

`cgrep` appears in the earliest editions of the Programming Perl (Camel) book. [It's pretty easy to find](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&sa=X&q=perl%20cgrep&nfpr=1).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggesting other options.
Actually i found that using 'flip-flop' operator with 'if' solves my problem very aptly. And after using this only i realized that asking a 'module' for a trivial task like this is too much from my side :).